# Recurrence Relation: T(n) = 2T(n/4) + T(n/2) + n^2

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

I've been working on these recurrence relations but I'm stumped on this one.

```
T(n) = 2T(n/4) + T(n/2) + n^2
```

I've seen them with one recursive call but not with two.

Comment: This belongs on [maths](http://math.stackexchange.com/) or perhaps [compsci](http://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

These sort of recurrences are solved with [Akra-Bazzi method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method).

In your case `a1 = 2, a2 = 1, b1 = 1/4, b2 = 1/2`. So you have to solve the equation:

```
2/4^p + 1/2^p = 1
```

whose solution is `p=1`. Now because your `g(x) = n^2`, your integral from 1 to x will be just `x - 1`. Therefore you complexity is just `x^p( 1 + x - 1) = O(x^2)`